# JavaFX equivalent to XCode layout

Tags: javafx-2

I'm sketching a UI in Scene Builder and was a bit surprised about the layout behaviors.

In XCode I'm used to define distance constraints so that widgets will stick to a side of a given container and won't overlap each other when window is resized.

In SB it seems that I have to wrap widgets in HBOXes before I can glue them to a corner in a parent Anchor container. Is that correct or am I missing something?

Also, I'd like to maintain a fixed distance between widgets but HBOX doesn't seem to provide one by default.

Is there a layout manager that provides "springy" distance minimums like Qt or Apple?

TIA,
Eddy

Comment: No, you don't need to wrap `Node`s in `HBox`es to place them in an `AnchorPane`. Just put them directly in the `AnchorPane` and set properties. `HBox` has a `spacing` property to put fixed space between child `Node`s. Read the [layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/package-summary.html) and [`Node`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html) Javadocs, the [layout tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/index.html), and see [this presentation](https://www.parleys.com/tutorial/interface-layout-javafx-2-0).

Comment: Related question: [Button alignment in JavaFX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16083683/button-alignment-in-javafx).  The spring/strut concept in conjunction with layout is often not needed, because usually the layout managers will take care of those concerns, but in case you need it, the idea of spring/strut regions is demonstrated in James Weaver's article on [Best Practices for JavaFX 2.0 Enterprise Applications](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javafxbest2-1634274.html) (just use FXML or procedural code for layout rather than the deprecated builders from that article).